# What's the best way to authenticate a user in a .net core 2 API programatically using Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm working on an application that has an angular 6 front end and a .net core 2.0 back-end and am trying to set it up so that my application authenticates users via Azure active directory. The issue is that I want the .net core back-end to do all the authentication programmatically when I have the front end pass an email and password. Everything that I've seen so far online suggests to have the front end redirect to the Microsoft login page but we are using our application as a boiler plate project and want to be able to change the type of authentication easily in the back-end without having to change the angular front-end. Does anyone know how I could go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) .The process will like that you collect the user credentials in Angular app and post to .net core back end , then finish the authentication in back-end app with user's credential. But that is **not recommended** because The ROPC flow requires a high degree of trust and user exposure and you should only use this flow when other, more secure, flows can't be used.

Also :

> - The Microsoft identity platform endpoint only supports ROPC for Azure AD tenants, not personal accounts. This means that you must use a tenant-specific endpoint (`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId_or_Name}`) or the `organizations` endpoint.
> - Personal accounts that are invited to an Azure AD tenant can't use ROPC.
> - Accounts that don't have passwords can't sign in through ROPC. For this scenario, we recommend that you use a different flow for your app instead.
> - If users need to use multi-factor authentication (MFA) to log in to the application, they will be blocked instead.

Reference :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc